# How can I access the computations done in a thread from main?

Tags: c, multithreading, pi

I am practicing creating 3 threads and computing a part of the Leibniz series to calculate pi. Everything works, but I can't access the result of the computations done in the threads to add the 3 numbers in main. Does anyone see the problem in the way I am returning them?

DRIVER.c:

```
/*Headers in evey file are this*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "driver.h"
#define thread_number 3

static float Pi = 3.141592;

void print_result(float * sums, float Final_pi, float error){
  int i;

  for(i = 1; i <= thread_number; i++)
   printf("Sum done by the thread number %i: %f\n", i, *(sums + i - 1));

  printf("The real PI: %f\n", Pi);
  printf("PI computed by the program: %f\n", Final_pi);
  printf("Error, aka difference between the two Pi above: %f\n", error);
}



int main(int argc, char** argv){   
  int i;/*variable for loops*/
  int iterations = atoi(argv[1]);/*number of iterations given by the user*/
  int error;
  float sum[thread_number] = {0.0f};
  data_struct args[thread_number];
  pthread_t thread_id[thread_number];
  float Final_pi = 0.0f;
  void* returns[3];


  if(argc == 0){
    printf("No arguments supplied\n");
    return -1;
  }

  if(argc > 2){
    printf("There are too many arguments\n");
    return -1;
  }


  args[0].mIterations = iterations;
  args[0].mFirst_value = 1;
  args[1].mIterations = iterations;
  args[1].mFirst_value = 2;
  args[2].mIterations = iterations;
  args[2].mFirst_value = 3;
  args[0].mSum = sum;
  args[1].mSum = sum+1;
  args[2].mSum = sum+2;



  for(i = 0; i < thread_number; i++){
    pthread_create(&thread_id[i], NULL, ComputePi, &args[i]);
    args[i].mFirst_value = i + 1;
    args[i].mIterations = iterations;
  }

  for(i = 0; i < thread_number; i++){
    pthread_join(thread_id[i], &returns[i]);
    args[i].mSum = (float*)returns[i];
    printf("%f\n",*args[i].mSum);
  }


/*Add the computations together*/
  for(i = 0; i < thread_number; i++)
    Final_pi += *args[i].mSum;


  error = Pi - Final_pi;

  print_result(sum, Final_pi, error);

  return 0;
}


pi.c:
/*code in threads*/

void* ComputePi(void * data){
  int i;
  int sign = 1;
  int denominator = 1;
  float sum = 0.0f;
  data_struct * args = (data_struct *)data;


  if(args->mFirst_value == 1){
    sign = 1;/*first number of the series*/
    denominator = 1;
  }
  else if (args->mFirst_value == 2){
    sign = (-1);/*second number of the series*/
    denominator = 3;
  }
  else if(args->mFirst_value == 3){
    sign = 1;/*Third number of the series*/
    denominator = 5;
  }

  /*loop to compute one of the 3 numbers that added together give us Pi*/
  for(i = args->mFirst_value; i <= args->mIterations; i = i+3){
    sum +=  sign * 4.0f / denominator;
    denominator += 6;
    sign *= -1;         
  }

  args->mSum = &sum;
  printf("mSum %f\n",*args->mSum);

  return (void*)args->mSum;
 }

driver.h:
void* ComputePi(void * data);

/*data_struct struct*/
typedef struct{
float * mSum;
int mIterations;
int mFirst_value;
}data_struct;
```

The printf in the thread gives me the actual results but the one in main just prints 0 3 times.

Comment: OT:  do not access beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to assure the user actually entered the desired number of command line parameters.  If things are not as expected, then output a `USAGE` statement to `stderr` then call `exit()`

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  there are several reasons, including `thread_number` is not defined and the needed include statements for the needed header files are missing.  Are you expecting us to guess as to which header files your actual code is including?

Comment: I added the headers included in evey file now as well as the code in each file. Sorry.

Comment: Please post the contents of `driver.h`

Comment: OT: when defining a struct, always include a 'tag' name as that is what a debugger uses to display the fields in the struct

Comment: What do you mean by a tag name?

Comment: regarding: `
  if(argc == 0){
    printf("No arguments supplied\n");
    return -1;
  }`   the function parameter: `argc` will NEVER be 0 because `argv[0]]` always contains a pointer to a char string that contains the execution name of the application that is running

Comment: ?tag name?   `struct <struct name> <tag name> { type fieldName; ...  };

Comment: Okay, thanks for improving my code, but can you tell me what I am asking please? I want to know how can I access the results of the threads

Comment: OT:  regarding this kind of statement: `printf("No arguments supplied\n");`   Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  There are two common ways to do this.  1) When the error indication comes from a library function, call `perror( "my error message" );` which will also output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred and 1) `fprintf( stderr, "my error message\n" ); for things like when the command line parameters are not correct

Comment: regarding: `args[i].mFirst_value = i + 1;
    args[i].mIterations = iterations;`  these have nothing to do with the problem and should be removed

Comment: regarding: `pthread_create(&thread_id[i], NULL, ComputePi, &args[i]);`  This does not compile because the compiler has not yet encountered the function `ComputePI()`  nor has it encountered a prototype for that function.  Suggest adding, before `main()` a statement like: `void* ComputePi(void * data);`

Comment: regarding: `int error;`  this is being set from the sum of three `float` values, so, it should also be declared as" `float error`

Comment: Man, that is already in driver.h. Please, answer what I am asking, and if you don't know, stop replying please.

Comment: You have not posted the contents of `driver.h` so how are we to know its' contents.  Strongly suggest when posting about a run time problem, that you post a [mcve] so we do not have to guess

Comment: The driver.h content is at the bottom of all the code. It is there. Please, read the questions before you answer. And the problem is already solved. Thank you for telling me little things wrong with the code, I really appreciate that, but this is just a piece of code that I am doing to practice, it does not have to be perfect.

Comment: You should always strive for your code to be perfect.  Also, the version of the code that I extracted (after your first (stated) edit, did not indicate that the end of the posted code is the contents of the `driver.h` file and it did not have the prototype for the thread function.

Comment: I found it necessary to comment on the problems with the posted code before supplying an answer to your question.  By the time I had commented on the problems with the posted code, another person had posted the reason the code is not working

Comment: Okay, thank you for the comments, I already fixed everything and everything works. I am looking forward to seeing you when I have another question to make! ;)

Answer (score 1):

`mSum` is a *pointer* to a `float`.

It is being set to the address of the `sum` variable which is in the *stack* frame of `ComputePi`. This goes out of scope when `ComputePi` exits/returns.

Change `mSum` to be `float mSum` and do `args->mSum = sum` instead of `args->mSum = &sum`

Then, just print `args[i].mSum` in `main`.

Note, there are other ways to organize this, but that is the simplest one.

Comment: And what do I return from ComputePi?

Comment: Okay, just changing it to float and returning a NULL pointer works. Thank you!

Comment: @JaviGuerra You can return just about anything that fits in a pointer. The _usual_ is often a return code (e.g. `return (void *) 0;`) or a pointer to a static scope error message, or whatever you'd like. Since you've already got space in _your_ `struct`, no need to return the value elsewhere. Note that if your thread function had to return _more_ than one value, you'd [most probably] _have_ to put it in your struct. If you wish, just for fun, you could return the `args/data` pointer value.

Comment: Okay, thanks you the explanation, I will definetly try returning the struct and play with it more tomorrow know that I know a little bit more how it works!

Comment: By the way, one more thing. If I return a struct, the pointer in the second parameter of pthread_join() would be pointing to that struct?

Comment: Yes, the second parameter in `pthread_join` would get that value. That's why I said "just for fun", since `main` already knows the addresses of all the structs passed to the thread function because it has control over the `args` array. Returning such a value would be useful if the thread function had to `malloc` a _different_ struct and/or array of values. But, then again, _that_ pointer could just be returned in your original struct as (e.g. `mPtr`)